# How to resolve MessageBodyWriter not found?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, tomcat7, media-type

Error:
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteToSEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/vnd.xyzcompany.v1+json, type=class model.OrderStatus, genericType=class model.OrderStatu

OrderStatus is a model class.

Facing this issue when trying to return the Object of class OrderStatus.

The main reason for this is Media Type, when i tried it using **application/json** it worked, but need to do it with **custom media type**
like: **application/vnd.xyzcompany.v1+json**

Extra Info:
@Produces and @Consumes are used with the same media type and OrderStatus class is defined in the response of the request.

Wherever I read mostly found that, custom mime/media type need to be registered but don't know how to register and implement.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom media/mime type and serializing/deserializing the received or sent object according to the new media type.

It just requires a class with "@Provider" annotation and a "@Produces". The produces annotation will be written as:  @Produces({"application/customType.v1+json", "application/json"}).

With a constructor/method having Object mapper serialization and deserialization.

NOTE: Keep this class in the package where all API classes are.

Example Code:

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/customType.v1+json"})
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public JacksonJsonProvider() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .registerModule(new JodaModule())
            .setDateFormat(new RFC3339DateFormat());

        setMapper(objectMapper);
    }
}
```